# place images around a circular image in android

Tags: android, imageview, xml-layout

I want to place images around a circular image and distributed equally and compatible for various screen sizes and i tried this link https://github.com/sababado/CircularView where as now i am facing problem which says

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-43
>       is also present at [com.sababado.circularview:library:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:4:45-81 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-24:19 to override.

i tried to change to change min sdk version and changed name of the icon.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPS1t.jpg)

Comment: see the last line of your error log

Comment: Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-24:19 to override. this is what your log says. so do it

Comment: in manifest under application tag add tools:replace="android:icon"

Comment: can you post your manifest code

Comment: Got it thanks, it's working